# Algorithm to place students in class room based on their preferences of seatmates

Tags: algorithm

I want to make a program that can make seat plans for my class. I want it so that each student can submit there preferences of seatmates in descending priority and that in end, every student is as satisfied as possible. I would prefer a situation in which two students are mildly satisfied over one where one sits perfect but the other one isn't satisfied at all.

Is there some kind of algorithm that efficiently solves this problem?
For example, I have four adjacent tables: ▀ ▀ ▀ ▀ and four students: *Alice*, *Bob*, *Chris* and *Dan*.

*Alice* and *Bob* both want to sit next to *Chris* but *Chris* wants to sit next to *Dan*. Additionally, *Alice* sets her second wish to not sit next to *Bob* or *Dan*. *Dan* doesn't care.

In this simple example, not all wishes can be satisfied, but since *Alice*' second wish was not to sit next to *Bob* or *Dan*, which cannot be satisfied as well, her first wish shall be used and *Chris*' not accounted. The distribution would look like this:
Alice, Chris, Bob and Dan

Comment: How are the chairs ordered? However - I would place them by random. Then try to replace pupil 1 while maximizing the benefit. Repeat for all pupils. However, this might only find a local optimum. Maybe better to place them one by one. 1st by choice. Find best fitting neighbor. Take next pupil, repeat.

Comment: Formalize the problem a bit. There is probably some geometry, e.g. 1 vs. 2 neighbors in some position.

Comment: I'm sorry, I accidently submitted the question. I finished it with this an edit. Thank you for your early answers!

Comment: What sizes are we talking about? How many positions / people? What kind of loss? (l1 vs. l2) -> difference between first and second wish.

Comment: Let's say, about 20 students and 30 seats, spread over 3 rows. So there are actually 10 seats that can be left free.

Comment: That's an important distinction. For small numbers, even average class sizes, an exhaustive search is possible. For larger groups probably not. :)

Comment: Another, not to underestimate role, plays the ranking systems. Depending on it, you can get different results, because combined rankings aren't associative. Think of 3 persons. 1 ranks ABC, one ranks BCA and one ranks CAB. You have a majority which ranks B over C, a majority for C before A but instead of B>C>A => B>A a majority for A before B.

Comment: This looks like a variant of the [stable marriage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem).

Comment: You can approach that with integer-programming. But as long as it looks like you did not invest more than 5 minutes to write your question, you should not expect ready-to-use answers. (additional info in comments unapplied to question; incomplete info given on scoring/loss; i asked for l1 vs. l2, what is *midly satisfied in math-terms?*; no info about rating-specification -> what rating is possible; ranking != ranking (what kind of order-relation; partial-ranking?); well-formatted example -> exploiting a more specified / math-based description: e.g. using the score / objective on the solution)